# How to display tooltip Parent value in child control

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

Using the following snippet and as I required to display the ToolTip from the parent element Grid. Unfortunately, it doesn't display the ToolTip.

```
<Grid Name="EmployeeValueGrid">
        <TextBlock  Text="Employee Department"
               TextWrapping="Wrap">
            <TextBlock.ToolTip>               
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}" />                
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
        </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

How can I acheive this ?

Answer (score 2):

Edited to address points in comment:

```
<Grid Name="EmployeeValueGrid" ToolTip="Grid Tooltip" >
    <TextBlock  Text="Employee Department"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" >
        <TextBlock.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.Parent}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ToolTip}"/>
            </ToolTip>
        </TextBlock.ToolTip>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's obviously what you are saying is correct. it was working me too. Assume my tootip has lengthy content so i decided to display inside of textblock that where i was showed in the post. That case not working.